# How to dynamically reference an element´s dynamically generated id

Tags: html, angularjs, web

I have this code:

```
    <div class="col-lg-12" data-ng-repeat="tda in allTipoDatosAlimentos">
        <div class="box dark">
           <header>
              <div class="icons"><i class="icon-edit"></i></div>
                  <h5>
                        <a class="accordion-toggle minimize-box" data-toggle="collapse" href="#div1">{{tda.nombreTipoDato}}
                        </a>
                  </h5>
                  <div class="toolbar">
                      <ul class="nav"> 
                         <li>
                             <a class="accordion-toggle minimize-box" data-toggle="collapse" href="#div1">
                                <i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>
                             </a>
                         </li>
                      </ul>
                   </div>
          </header>
          <div id="div1" class="accordion-body collapse body">
              <div class="input-group" data-ng-repeat="nut in tda.nutrientesList">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                       <abbr title="{{nut.nombre}}">{{nut.abreviatura}}</abbr> 
                  </span>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">{{nut.idUnidadMedida.unidadMedida}}
                        </span>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

And I need to generate the id of the  dynamically. I know it can be done by: id={{tda.idTipoDatosAlimentos}} .... Thats fine but how can I reference that  ??
I tried  but the IDE gives this error:
'#{...} not allowed in a template text body'
I really need help on this one.

Comment: " Thats fine but how can I reference that ??"  where?

Comment: Depending where you need it you might use only: tda.idTipoDatosAlimentos

Comment: thanks for the quick response, but i found a way, ill post the answer below now. Again thanks for responding

Answer (score 0):

I discover how to solve my problem,

```
<div id="{{'div' + tda.idTiposDatosAlimentos}}" class="accordion-body collapse body">
```

I setted this id like an expression {{'div' + tda.idTipoDatosAlimentos}}, this generates this id:

```
<div id='div1'>
```

for the first element inside the ng-repeat.
Then to reference that id, i can do this:

```
<a href="#div{{tda.idTiposDatosAlimentos}}">
```

wich again generates this:

```
<a href='div1'>
```

for the first element of the ng-repeat.
:)
Hope this works for someone else someday.